# Anagram Sort Last Step

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to perform anagram sort, and I did it till here:

I sorted each `string` in the `array`, stored it into `hashmap`.

Now I have a map with keys as string with values as anagrams of that string.

Here is the code:

```
public static void anagramSort(String[] s){

        HashMap<String, Set<String>> h=new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        String temp[]=new String[s.length];
        Set<String> result=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){    

            char[] c=s[i].toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(c);
            temp[i]=new String(c);

            if(h.containsKey(temp[i])){
                Set<String> s1=new TreeSet<String>();
                s1.addAll(h.get(temp[i]));
                s1.add(s[i]);
                h.put(temp[i], s1);
            }
            else{
                Set<String> s2=new TreeSet<String>();
                s2.add(s[i]);
                h.put(temp[i], s2);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(h);
    }
```

Now I would like to place all these values of hashmap into a string array or a set so that all the anagrams will be together.

I tried to place them(values in the hashmap) in a set, but it is getting clumsier.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You're having sorted strings as key and the set of all input strings that are anagrams of that key as values, right? I think your description and code are not in line now - or I just misunderstood the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the `values()` and collect them to a `List`:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> h = ...; // The map created in the OP

List<String> allAnagrams = new LinkedList<>();
for (Set<String> anagrams : h.values()) {
    allAnagrams.addAll(anagrams);
}
```